# How do I access different form's object for my windows form app

Tags: winforms

I have like 2 or 3 different forms and for example for my mainForm, I would like to access the object in settingsForm. How do I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose that object, via a public property on settingsForm.

e.g.

In your settings form:

```
public Object MyObject
{
get { return myobject; } 
}

then, on your main form, your can say;

settingsForm sf = new settingsForm();
sf.Show();

...

Console.Write(sf.MyObject.Text);
```

So. let's say settingsForm has a textbox that stores a value you want.

If you need access to the entire text box, you'd add a property on settings forms....

```
public TextBox textbox1
{
    get { return textbox1; }
}
```

then, any form that instantiates and uses settingsForm, can use textbox1.

If you only want to access the value in textbox1, you'd only expose its Text property.

```
public string TextBoxValue
{
    get { return textbox1.Text; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    settingForm settingObject;

    public mainForm(settingForm settingObject)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.settingObject= settingObject;
    }

}
```

the above code shows a simple way of how you access the object.